# Checking for remote modifications using subversion

Tags: svn

svn status gives the list of updates in my working copy. Tools like TortoiseSVN etc also show the list of remote modifications.
Is there a svn command that i can run to get a list of remote modifications given the url of the remote repository ?

Please Help
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn log URL -v --limit 10` will show you the latest 10 modifications with files changed in each of them.

`svn log URL -rREV:HEAD -v` will show all modifications since revision REV.